# Receiving large amount of data effectively in Java Servlets

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I am getting a large amount of data from an HTML form, using POST method.

```
req.getParameter();
```

returns the value as String, but I am getting a value that is so large that it needs StringBuilder.

What do I do ?

Comment: How much large? When i've tested it last time (it was 2003), String has been working fine for strings up to 160mb

Comment: @IgorArtamonov Can String really hold THAT big a value ?? i am working with 1~2mb

Comment: 1-2mb must be not a problem. Anyway, you can use `request.getInputStream()`, as Torius have suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be various limits, depending on servlet implementation, of POST parameter sizes. See

[Tomcat POST parameter limit (default 2mb)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943477/is-there-a-max-size-for-post-parameter-contenthttp://)

[Setting Jetty POST parameter limits (default <200k)](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Form_Size)

GAE servlet container is based on Jetty 6, but concrete implementation limitations are AFAIK not known. Google guys, anyone got some concrete numbers on max POST parameter size?