# What is the maximum number of hidden input fields I can put under a form?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

For example, I have a form which contains tons of `<input type="hidden" name="allsame">` and **each one has different and unique value but has the same name ("allsame")**.

After the form was submitted, it seems that many 'allsame' inputs are missing and I can receive some of them but not all.

So I wonder that Java/Tomcat has limitted the number of input fields under a form?

If yes, how can I increase it and increase to which number?

Comment: I want to retrieve it as an array. That's why I give it the same name.

Comment: I am thinking more about a GET or POST size limit than a number of fields

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie - Thanks, I will check it http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `INPUT` fields limitation inside a `FORM`, the only limit is the size of the request.

**GET**

For `GET` actions it looks like the limit is between 255B and 8KB, depending on server configuration and browsers, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2659995/354831).

**POST**

For POST actions, it depends on the server configuration, the default for Tomcat is 2MB, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2943515/354831) for more informations.

Comment: I think this must be an answer. I have to try it first and see it can solve my problem.

Comment: @AtthaponJunpun-eak is your form action GET or POST?