# Send large amount of text to servlet via form

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, servlets

I'm working on Java Servlet. I have form on my jsp file and I am sending huge amount of text from form to servlet it sends to servlet successfully but, I can't get any parameters from request object get parameters are always null on my servlet class, if I send less amount of text when pass to servlet working perfectly. I don't know how to solve this problem. Can you know this problem solution help me. I will appreciate your effect.

```
Huge amount of text count. It's above 50,000
```

Comment: what is the method GET or POST ?

Comment: i used POST method in form

Comment: is that you have used larger text in a single parameter or too many parameters...

Comment: sorry single parameter for huge amount of text

Comment: Looks like this is same as [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943477/is-there-a-max-size-for-post-parameter-content

Comment: try increasing the maxPostSize, by setting it in server.xml..i think it is 2mb by default

Comment: ok buddy i will try it and post status :)

Comment: is there any exception thrown.post your code first.

Comment: yes throws null pointer exception in servlet class on getparameter method line

Comment: @StackOverflowUser it has to be the thing varra and i have sugggested..

Comment: @StackOverflowUser can you post your code

Comment: @StackOverflowUser so did our suggestions help u?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit Tomcat's server.xml. In the  element, add an attribute maxPostSize and set a larger value (in bytes) to increase the limit.
if `maxPostSize="0"` it means it is unlimited..

Comment: i have problem how to response write max size?

Comment: meaning?i didnt get u.@StackOverflowUser

Comment: i response write excel file via servlet but, large amount of data write on these file can't open these file.

Comment: try increasing this `maxHttpHeaderSize`

Comment: on same tomcat server.xml?

Comment: yup...check this SO question too  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947683/httprequest-maximum-allowable-size-in-tomcat

Comment: i am off for lunch..if it helps,plz tick my answer..or else if u have more problem v can solve wen i return..

Answer (score 0):

You should check your tomcat version, if bigger than 7 `maxPostSize="0"` will not effect, setting `maxPostSize="-1"` is ok.