# Request entity too large error

Tags: java, apache, apache2, tomcat7

Currently in my project, I am getting the following errors

```
1) Request entity too large error, The requested resource does not allow request Data with GET Requests, or the amount of the data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit
2) Request entity too large error, The requested resource does not allow request Data with POST Requests, or the amount of the data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit**
```

I get these error while I submit my pages at different modules. I use tomcat 7 and apache in my project. I have made changes in tomcats server.xml as

```
<Connector port="8109" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" maxPostSize="-1" packetSize="65536"/>
```

But I am still getting the same error. Can anyone guide me where else I need to make changes to avoid this problem?

Comment: Take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943477/is-there-a-max-size-for-post-parameter-content

Comment: @Octopus thanks for your link. i have tried it but still is not helpful. Can u provide some other soln???

Comment: Since you are using the AJP connector you must have a reverse proxy such as Apache httpd. You'll need to raise the limits in httpd.conf as well.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit old thread, but just in case if anyone come across this one.

> 413 request entity too large

If your url encounter this error when trying to download large files, modify the configuration as below.

Edit your **workers.properties** file for the site.

On Ubuntu, this could be typically at

> /etc/libapache2-mod-jk/workers.properties

Add

> worker.<yoursite>.max_packet_size=65536