# Request entity too large error by Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat

Request entity too large error, The requested resource does not allow request Data with GET(OR POST) Requests, or the amount of the data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

I use tomcat 7 and apache in my project. I made changes in tomcat's server.xml as

```
<Connector port="8109" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" maxPostSize="-1" packetSize="65536"/>
```

still getting the same error.

Comment: What is the value of [`maxPostSize`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943477/is-there-a-max-size-for-post-parameter-content) on your `<Connector>`?

Comment: <Connector port="8109" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" maxPostSize="-1" packetSize="65536"/>

Comment: Post that by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/36954099/edit), not in a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your advice Boris.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is coming from Tomcat and not your Apache httpd front end?

Comment: the above error message from apache logs.