# Is there any way to put limit on the number of `form parameters` to send to the server?

Tags: http-post, grails-2.2

I am using Grails 2.2 and I have an email form which sends mass emails. This form is submitted to the server via `POST` request. This form has lots of checkboxes to select the emails to deliver the message to. The number of emails can be greater than 1000. Apparently, grails has a limit on the number of form parameters sent via POST and I think I am crossing this limit.

Below is the sample of the post parameters sent to the server. The number of parameters can be lot larger than the shown sample.

```
_select_all:
_select_all:
_participant:
_select_all:
_select_all:
_participant:
_select_all:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_select_all:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
_participant:
subject:test
body:test
emails:asd@asd.com
count_emails:0
create:Send
```

I cannot increase the form parameter limit size since in `Grails 2.2`. This limit was added in Grails later than 2.2. So, I wanted to know what are some ways that these parameters can be reduced. One way i was thinking was to somehow limit the number of parameters using javascript and sending the post request using ajax rather than normal form submission. I appreciate any input. Thanks!

Comment: I have done this before: If you can run a function when the submit button is pressed you can delete all the checkboxes that aren't checked and then only the checked ones will be sent.

Comment: possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568039/is-there-any-limit-on-the-number-of-parameters-allowed-in-post-request-to-the-se

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting any `limit` or incresing the `default` number of allowed parameters, you can simply reduce the number of parameters by `pushing` all the `email recipent` to the `list` while submitting the form.

Also in that case, there might be possibility of exceeding the `size` of the `request content` as you are sending the large volume of data.

There are configuration parameters provided to change this setting.You need to change your default tomcat configuration for that.

You can find more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568039/is-there-any-limit-on-the-number-of-parameters-allowed-in-post-request-to-the-se).