# Can't submit import form when large data in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I have 2 jsp page includes (confirm_data.jsp, saveDb_data.jsp). 
1st step: Read data from excel file show on confirm_data.jsp page. 
2nd step: User click button 'Save'-> call the submit form function to saveDb_data.jsp page . I used

```
<form name="fForm" method="POST" action="saveDb_data.jsp">
....
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

When i have 20 or 30 rows data -> save ok. But when 200 rows data -> can't submit to saveDb_data.jsp. Show error[image]

How to resolve it?
p/s : i running jsp on tomcat

Comment: What is the response code error and message. What is the server showing, did he received the request and rejected it for any reason? Can you [edit] your question with more information please. 200 rows doesn't provide much idea of the sizing of your request. If you get a an [`IllegalStateException: Post too large`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/123335/4391450), then [change the limit in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2943477/4391450)

Comment: thanks @AxelH,  the server doesn't  log to catalina.out, let me  change the limit in Tomcat